# R how to selectively sort a data frame?

Tags: r, sorting, dataframe

I have the following example data frame in R.

```
  item index  ptr
     A     1 0.40
     B     2   NA
     C     3 0.30
     D     4 0.35
     E     5 0.44
     F     6   NA
```

It is already sorted based on column = `index`. Now, I would like to sort it by the column `ptr` but by leaving the position of rows where `ptr` = `NA` intact. So the output I'm expecting is:

```
  item index  ptr
     C     3 0.30
     B     2   NA
     D     4 0.35
     A     1 0.40
     E     5 0.44
     F     6   NA
```

The regular `df = df[order(ptr),]` doesn't work. Any ideas? Thanks much in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try this:

```
> df
  item index  ptr
1    A     1 0.40
2    B     2   NA
3    C     3 0.30
4    D     4 0.35
5    E     5 0.44
6    F     6   NA
> df[!is.na(df$ptr), ] <- df[order(df$ptr, na.last = NA), ]
> df
  item index  ptr
1    C     3 0.30
2    B     2   NA
3    D     4 0.35
4    A     1 0.40
5    E     5 0.44
6    F     6   NA
```

Comment: That's more succinct (and understandable) than my approach.

Comment: I like this approach. Thanks for solution. It is definitely terse and well thought out.

Answer (score 4):

```
ptr.na <- is.na(df$ptr)
order.idx <- seq(length=nrow(df))
ptr.idx <- which(!ptr.na)
order.idx[!ptr.na] <- ptr.idx[order(df[ptr.idx,"ptr"])]
df[order.idx,]
```

gives

```
> df[order.idx,]
  item index  ptr
3    C     3 0.30
2    B     2   NA
4    D     4 0.35
1    A     1 0.40
5    E     5 0.44
6    F     6   NA
```

Comment: I like your approach because there is no side effect.